# Non-bluelight monitor only works on one?

Tags: 18.04

I have the Ububtu 18.04 setting to turn off blue-light frequencies on the monitor from dusk til dawn, but for some reason it only seems to work on one monitor, in this case my external one?

Anyone know why it doesn't work on both?

You can see the diff between the two monitors in the screenshot:

[image]

Here's the settings:

[image]

Comment: If someone could create a tag "night-light" or "blue-light" or something that might be good idk.

Comment: I suppose it could just be the monitors being different in terms of hardware, but my laptop screen doesn't really look much different, so I would guess that the redshift/blueshift thing isn't working on it but idk.